# Google Apps Marketplace - grant access

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

The scenario:

- installing google apps marketplace app
- user grant access using oauth2 and some predefined scopes
- user clicks on a link after installation
- since the user already gave access to the same app he is not forced to grant access again (as we have authentication in the app itself), but only to login if the current session is expired

The problem:

- even we set the same app settings + scopes, it's asking twice for the "grant access" - in marketplace + our app

Clues so far:

- if we wait (3-4 minutes) between marketplace grant access and clicking the app link .. it's working and it's NOT forcing the user to grant access again, so all cool.. apart from waiting time
- if we use only the marketplace auth, the app permission is NOT present here: https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions So even granted, I cannot revoke it from here
- if we use auth in our app (the second one) - it's now present in the above link and can be revoked

I can see something's wrong, but can't figure out what. Is there some "google apps specific login" apart from the standard Google Auth APIs? Or what about that waiting moment and then all works good? All suggestions are welcome! :)

Comment: It doesn't sound like you're doing anything wrong. Rather, it appears that there is some latency on the backend propagating the authorization for the domain. This has been a known issue, though usually it's on the order of seconds, not minutes.

Comment: Unfortunately nothing new so far.
I checked everything - scopes, keys, settings...
Tried several times to install on cleared account and the only way to avoid double "grant access" is to to wait a bit between the 2 calls (this time just 20-30 seconds) and it is working. This is very frustrating as we cannot publish the app... I've read again all documentations and .. nothing.

Comment: Could you let me know the project id and domain name you're trying with? You can email to sbazyl@goo***.com